# simplification of FOC

Tags: macroeconomics, nonexpert, dynamic-programming

This is the first-order condition of a dynamic programming problem where I am trying to get the Euler equation from a sequential problem.

(1) $$\frac{\partial V(d_2)}{\partial d_3} = \frac{-1}{d_2-d_3} + \frac{\beta}{d_3} = 0$$

(2)$$d_3 = \frac{\beta d_2}{1+\beta}$$

Can anyone plz show the steps of this simplification from stage (1) to stage (2)?

Comment: Have you actually tried solving the FOC for $d_3$?

Comment: Since the OP took the time to rewrite the question from a picture into math-setting I assume the OP has also tried the algebra and is desperate. Hint: Try multiplying with $d_2-d_3$ ...

Comment: @JesperHybel That wasn't OP.

Comment: Haha ok my bad ....

Answer (score 3):

Rearrange
$$\frac{-1}{d_2-d_3} + \frac{\beta}{d_3} = 0$$
to
$$\frac{\beta}{d_3} = \frac{1}{d_2-d_3}$$
Flip it:
$$\frac{d_3}{\beta} = d_2-d_3$$
The equation is now linear in $d_3$.